# Check and cast multiindex types

Tags: python, pandas

How can I check a Pandas' Multiindex type for each of its levels?
I'm trying to access a specific level in order to check whether its type is what I want it to be, and if not, cast it to an `int` type.

I've tried `df.index.info()` with no success. I've also checked the methods and attributes described in the [API Reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.html#pandas.MultiIndex), though I don't see any mention to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setup

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(2), [*'XY']], names=['lvl0', 'lvl1'])
df = pd.DataFrame(1, idx, idx)
df

lvl0       0     1   
lvl1       X  Y  X  Y
lvl0 lvl1            
0    X     1  1  1  1
     Y     1  1  1  1
1    X     1  1  1  1
     Y     1  1  1  1
```

---

### Basic Anatomy of a MultiIndex

#### `levels`

Is a `frozenlist` of `pandas.Index` objects.  Each of these `pandas.Index` objects should contain unique values.  If these level index objects are not unique, something is probably broken.

```
[*map(type, df.index.levels)]

[pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index, pandas.core.indexes.base.Index]
```

you can get at their `dtype`

```
[l.dtype for l in df.index.levels]

[dtype('int64'), dtype('O')]
```

---

#### `labels`

This is a `frozenlist` of arrays.  There is a one label array for each level index.  The corresponding label array contains reference to which level values are being displayed.

```
[*map(type, df.index.labels)]

[pandas.core.indexes.frozen.FrozenNDArray,
 pandas.core.indexes.frozen.FrozenNDArray]
```

---

```
print(*df.index.labels, sep='\n')

FrozenNDArray([0, 0, 1, 1], dtype='int8')
FrozenNDArray([0, 1, 0, 1], dtype='int8')
```

---

#### `get_level_values`

You can access the values in an index with `get_level_values`

```
df.index.get_level_values(1)

Index(['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y'], dtype='object', name='lvl1')
```

Which would be the same as slicing the `level` object with the `label` object

```
df.index.levels[1][df.index.labels[1]]

Index(['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y'], dtype='object', name='lvl1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `get_level_values`

```
df.index.get_level_values(0).dtype
Out[19]: dtype('int64')
```

Comment: this is a good answer, but for the sake of completeness I've marked the other one as accepted. Thanks anyways!